# Android Room Database: Difference between OnConflictStrategy.ABORT vs IGNORE

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

What is the difference between `OnConflictStrategy.ABORT` and `OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE` in Room Database?

- `ABORT`: roll back the transaction on conflict
- `IGNORE`: keep the existing rows

I know both of them won't add a new row when there is an existed row.

1. what is really the difference between these?
2. In What case we must use them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A transaction usually consists of more than 1 `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements.

Depending on your requirement you must decide what happens if any of these statements violate a  `UNIQUE`, `NOT NULL`, `CHECK` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

Do you want the transaction to stop when the first violation occurs and rollback the changes made by the statement that caused the violation?
If the answer is *yes* then you must use `ABORT`, which is the default behavior.

Do you want the transaction to continue with the next statement, if any of the statements violates a constraint by just ignoring and not actually executing that problematic statement?
If the answer is *yes* then you must use `IGNORE`.

Answer (score 4):

There is differences between `ABORT` and `IGNORE`. `ABORT` will cancel the transaction if you try to insert object that has same key or unique constraint and throw :

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException:
```

while `IGNORE` ignore conflict, won't throw exception and return -1 as id number  if your insert method is like this :

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
 long insert(SoundCardModel soundCardModel);
```

instead of this :

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
 void insert(SoundCardModel soundCardModel);
```

for reading :

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy